# Best way to run two task independently.

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

What is the best way run two block of code independently and join before third block.

Actually I m planning to design custom java based work flow.
And my requirement is to run two process independently and join at third process.

I don't want to create thread manually and join on it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the two blocks of code? Do they yield values?

Comment: I have one file ...! first block is to upload file on s3 and second block to copy that file two hdfs using ssh . what I want to create one abstract level design to decide task run async or in sync and also decide task will wait for all previous task or not (based on some flag).

Comment: How could you possibly run those two tasks independently?

Comment: file in local file system .. as I know more than one thread can access same file at same time (read) .So what I have done this create two thread and join.But I want to use some design pattern or some already exists framework to make this task to  easy ,No need to create and join thread.

Comment: True. How many network connections do you have?

Comment: can u explain role of network connection?

Comment: one connection for ssh and one  http connection to access s3

Comment: Thread a connects to s3, thread b connects to your two hdfs systems. Now a and b write at slightly less then half the speed they would if you operated them serially (because you don't magically get more bandwidth).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using java 8?  [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) is very handy:

```
import static java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.allOf;
import static java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.runAsync;

....


allOf(
        runAsync(() -> {
            // do first thing
        }),
        runAsync(() -> {
            // do second thing
        })
).join();
// do third thing
```

There are a lot of options, of course.  For one, if you are doing IO, you would probably want to supply an executor to runAsync.

Comment: I m working with java 7